# How to find out the real cause of system soft lock?

Tags: linux, memory, linux-kernel, cpu, watchdog

I have two database nodes, and this is one of them, yesterday the other one had a system soft lock problem and i unable to solve the soft lock problem in a short time. so I restart it . And now this node also has a system soft lock too. And this is my production database!!,god, someone who can help me to find out what is the real cause of the soft lockup
my linux version and os is:

```
[root@database02 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)
[root@database02 ~]# uname -a
Linux database02 4.1.12-112.16.4.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Mon Mar 12 23:57:12 PDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@database02 ~]#
```

Part of system log like below:

```
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#7 stuck for 22s! [ping:163683]
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Modules linked in: nbd fuse btrfs xor raid6_pq vfat msdos fat ext3 mbcache jbd ext2 cdp(OE) ip_set_bitmap_port ip_set_hash_ipport ip_set_hash_ipportnet ip_set_hash_ipportip dummy tcp_diag inet_diag binfmt_misc xt_set xt_multiport iptable_raw iptable_mangle ip_set_hash_ip ip_set_hash_net ipip tunnel4 ip_tunnel ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6_tables nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 dns_resolver nfs lockd grace fscache veth nf_conntrack_netlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay xt_statistic xt_nat ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_mark xt_comment xt_conntrack ip_set nfnetlink iptable_filter xt_addrtype iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_vs_sh ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_rr ip_vs nf_conntrack
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: sunrpc ext4 jbd2 mbcache2 ppdev parport_pc parport virtio_balloon sg i2c_piix4 acpi_cpufreq pcspkr ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom ata_generic virtio_net virtio_blk virtio_console virtio_scsi pata_acpi cirrus syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt drm_kms_helper ttm ata_piix drm virtio_pci libata virtio_ring serio_raw i2c_core virtio floppy dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CPU: 7 PID: 163683 Comm: ping Tainted: G           OEL Z 4.1.12-112.16.4.el7uek.x86_64 #2
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.7.5-0-ge51488c-20140602_164612-nilsson.home.kraxel.org 04/01/2014
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: task: ffff880d00331c00 ti: ffff8809815e8000 task.ti: ffff8809815e8000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8174e4aa>]  [<ffffffff8174e4aa>] _raw_spin_lock+0x6a/0xd0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff8809815ebbc8  EFLAGS: 00000202
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RAX: 000000000000169b RBX: ffff880981448200 RCX: 0000000000000062
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RDX: 00000000000092bc RSI: 00000000000092de RDI: ffffffff821560b8
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RBP: ffff8809815ebbe8 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: R10: ffffea003a680140 R11: ffffffff8163d6a2 R12: ffffffff8174fc53
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: R13: ffffffff8174fc5a R14: ffffffff8174fc61 R15: ffffffff8174fc68
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: FS:  00007fa52355b740(0000) GS:ffff880ffbdc0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CR2: 00007fa523566000 CR3: 0000000974c9e000 CR4: 0000000000000670
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Stack:
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: 00000000000000c0 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 00000000000000a0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: ffff8809815ebc78 ffffffff811d80a5 ffff8809815ebcf8 ffffffff00000001
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: ffff8809815ebc90 ffff8809815ebc88 00000000000000d0 ffff8809815ebc20
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811d80a5>] __purge_vmap_area_lazy+0x135/0x390
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811f82d0>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_node_trace+0x240/0x2b0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811d8437>] vm_unmap_aliases+0x137/0x160
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81072ee0>] change_page_attr_set_clr+0xf0/0x520
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8163d6a2>] ? bpf_convert_filter+0x9c2/0xa60
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81073e6f>] set_memory_ro+0x2f/0x40
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81180289>] bpf_prog_select_runtime+0x29/0x40
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8163d8b3>] bpf_prepare_filter+0x173/0x190
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8163db6e>] sk_attach_filter+0xee/0x1e0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8160ee56>] sock_setsockopt+0x3f6/0x940
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff816095e6>] SyS_setsockopt+0xe6/0x100
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e791>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xdb/0x18c
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e85a>] system_call_fastpath+0x18/0xd4
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Code: 08 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 41 89 d4 45 31 ed 48 33 c0 66 90 85 c0 75 65 41 0f b7 f4 b8 00 80 00 00 eb 0e 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 90 <83> e8 01 74 40 0f b7 13 89 d1 44 31 e1 81 e1 fe ff 00 00 75 e9
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 22s! [sshd:163779]
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Modules linked in: nbd fuse btrfs xor raid6_pq vfat msdos fat ext3 mbcache jbd ext2 cdp(OE) ip_set_bitmap_port ip_set_hash_ipport ip_set_hash_ipportnet ip_set_hash_ipportip dummy tcp_diag inet_diag binfmt_misc xt_set xt_multiport iptable_raw iptable_mangle ip_set_hash_ip ip_set_hash_net ipip tunnel4 ip_tunnel ip6table_nat nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_nat_ipv6 ip6_tables nfsv3 nfs_acl rpcsec_gss_krb5 auth_rpcgss nfsv4 dns_resolver nfs lockd grace fscache veth nf_conntrack_netlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay xt_statistic xt_nat ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_mark xt_comment xt_conntrack ip_set nfnetlink iptable_filter xt_addrtype iptable_nat nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_vs_sh ip_vs_wrr ip_vs_rr ip_vs nf_conntrack
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: sunrpc ext4 jbd2 mbcache2 ppdev parport_pc parport virtio_balloon sg i2c_piix4 acpi_cpufreq pcspkr ip_tables xfs libcrc32c sr_mod cdrom ata_generic virtio_net virtio_blk virtio_console virtio_scsi pata_acpi cirrus syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt drm_kms_helper ttm ata_piix drm virtio_pci libata virtio_ring serio_raw i2c_core virtio floppy dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CPU: 8 PID: 163779 Comm: sshd Tainted: G           OEL Z 4.1.12-112.16.4.el7uek.x86_64 #2
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.7.5-0-ge51488c-20140602_164612-nilsson.home.kraxel.org 04/01/2014
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: task: ffff8808f9f9d400 ti: ffff880980814000 task.ti: ffff880980814000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8174e4aa>]  [<ffffffff8174e4aa>] _raw_spin_lock+0x6a/0xd0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffff880980817c58  EFLAGS: 00000202
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RAX: 000000000000236c RBX: ffffffff81359980 RCX: 0000000000000058
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RDX: 00000000000092bc RSI: 00000000000092e4 RDI: ffffffff821560b8
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: RBP: ffff880980817c78 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: R10: ffffea0039714800 R11: ffffffff81148d70 R12: ffffffff8174fc53
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: R13: ffffffff8174fc5a R14: ffffffff8174fc61 R15: ffffffff8174fc68
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: FS:  00007fadbc696880(0000) GS:ffff880ffbe00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: CR2: 00007ffc688d9f84 CR3: 000000083d910000 CR4: 0000000000000670
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Stack:
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: ffffea000de07000 0000000000000001 0000000000000001 00000000000000a0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: ffff880980817d08 ffffffff811d80a5 ffff880d00e92d00 ffff880800000001
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: ffff880980817d20 ffff880980817d18 00000000d421db98 ffff880980817cb0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Call Trace:
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811d80a5>] __purge_vmap_area_lazy+0x135/0x390
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811d8437>] vm_unmap_aliases+0x137/0x160
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81072ee0>] change_page_attr_set_clr+0xf0/0x520
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8163d6a2>] ? bpf_convert_filter+0x9c2/0xa60
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81073e6f>] set_memory_ro+0x2f/0x40
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81180289>] bpf_prog_select_runtime+0x29/0x40
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff81148d8d>] do_seccomp+0x88d/0x8e0
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff810701e9>] ? __do_page_fault+0x1c9/0x460
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff811491c4>] prctl_set_seccomp+0x24/0x50
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8109f631>] SyS_prctl+0x3a1/0x490
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e7a6>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xf0/0x18c
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e79f>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xe9/0x18c
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e791>] ? system_call_after_swapgs+0xdb/0x18c
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: [<ffffffff8174e85a>] system_call_fastpath+0x18/0xd4
Mar 29 17:30:04 database02 kernel: Code: 08 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 41 89 d4 45 31 ed 48 33 c0 66 90 85 c0 75 65 41 0f b7 f4 b8 00 80 00 00 eb 0e 0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00 f3 90 <83> e8 01 74 40 0f b7 13 89 d1 44 31 e1 81 e1 fe ff 00 00 75 e9
```

Comment: If you are using a RedHat, you are probably better off with their support (since that's exactly what you are paying). It seems that you are running two VMs under QEMU (probably with KVM). Have you tried the [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39542)? It's old but it may be still relevant. The kernel 4.1 is also old (with 5.6 being available) but that's how RedHat/CentOS work. Another reason to ask them. Older kernels may have bugs when dealing with (now) common hardware.

Comment: +1 to the *"If you are using a RedHat, you are probably better off with their support"* - not necessarily saying that this isn't a valid question, but they are precisely paid to support you.